# How to assign multiple variables values in one line in R?

Tags: r

**The question:**
Generate a response vector Y of length n = 100 according to the cubic model: =0+1+2^2+3^3+ where β0, β1, β2, and β3 are constants of your own choice.

**I am trying to assign random integers to the 4 beta's. I wonder if I can assign them with different values in one line in R?**

My approach is as follows:

```
beta_0, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you try using an atomic vector `beta <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)` and access by index `i`: `beta[i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `list2env` by placing it in a `named` `list`

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(1:4), paste0("beta_", 0:3)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

But, it may be better to work on the `list` itself instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment

Comment: Hello @akrun, when you mention that _"it may be better to work on the list itself"_, you mean because it is less object-load in the global environment, or because it is easier to assign the values in a compact way? If the last one, could you provide an example of it? Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.GutiérrezVargas I meant it is easier to work on the `list` and later write it back as you can always use `lapply/sapply/vapply` etc to loop over the list and do the transformations